# Smooth playing of video in javafx. Any solution?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, mouseevent, minimize, maximize-window

> I am trying to play videos from a folder which will play continously in a cycle. The videos are playing continously but not smoothly I want it to play smoothly. I know where the problem is but I am not finding any suitabe solution on it. The problem is that I am trying to execute a function continously after every 1.3 seconds of interval.But every time the video stops slightly and then it play. Can any one give me a solution on this? Thanks in advance
>
> Controller Code:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    try{            
            Timer time = new Timer();
            TimerTask st = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                    //displaytext(); 
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        displaytext();
                        try {
                            displaytextbox();
                        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(UTSfxmlController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    });                                
                }                    
            };
            time.scheduleAtFixedRate(st, 0, 1300);           
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }       
    try{
        initPlayer(); 
    }catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        
}
```